# Fread() and fwrite () function

Tags: c, fread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void delay (int milliseconds); // for delay function 
void menu (); //for choosing a menu
void addacc(); // for adding account
void view ();  // for viewing existing list
struct date
{
   int date, month, year;    //struct for date
};

struct customer
{
   char name[40],acctype[10];
   int accno, age;
   double phone;
   float amount;
   struct date dob;   //calling other struct inside struct
   struct date deposit;
   struct date withdraw;
} add;   //struct variable

void addacc()
{


   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen ("cus.txt", "a+");
   textcolor (1);
   printf ("\n\t\t\t\t");
   cprintf ("ADD RECORD");
   printf("\n\n\n");
   printf ("Enter today's date(date/month/year) \n");
   scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &add.deposit.date, &add.deposit.month,&add.deposit.year);
   printf ("Enter account number\n");
   scanf ("%d", &add.accno);
   printf ("Enter customer's name\n");
   scanf ("%s", add.name);
   printf ("Enter customer's age\n");
   scanf ("%d", &add.age);   printf ("Enter customer's phone num\n");
   scanf ("%f",&add.phone);
   printf ("Enter the account type(in words): \n\t 1:Current\n\t 2:Saving\n\t 3:Fixed\n");
   scanf ("%s",&add.acctype);
   textcolor (2);
   cprintf ("Almost done! Just enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
   scanf ("%f",&add.amount);

   fwrite (&add,sizeof(add),1,fp);
   fclose (fp);

}

void view ()
{
   FILE *view;
   int test=0;
   system ("cls");
   textcolor (3);
   printf ("\n\t\t\t\t");
   cprintf ("Customer's List");
   printf ("\n\n\n");
   textcolor(4);
   cprintf ("\tCustomer's Name:");
   cprintf ("\tAccount Number:");
   cprintf ("\tCustomer's Phone No:");
   view=fopen("cus.txt", "r");

   while(fread(&add, sizeof(add),1,view)!=0)
   {
      printf ("%s", add.name);
      printf ("%d", add.accno);
      printf ("%f", add.phone);
      test++;

   }
   fclose (view);
   if (test==0)
   {
      printf ("NO RECORDS FOUND!");
   }
}

void menu ()
{ 
   int n;
   printf ("Enter your choice 1, 2\n");
   scanf ("%d", &n);

   switch (n)

   {
      case 1:
         addacc();
         break;
      case 2:
         view ();
         break;
   }
} 

void main (void)
{ 
   system ("cls");

   menu ();
}
```

Output: when you choose 1 as option

ADD RECORD
Enter today's date
Enter customer's name
etc
output: when you choose option 2 for viewing the list of existing customers
screen blank

So I would like to know is my syntax of fread wrong or of fwrite? why isn't it showing on the screen the entries which I just entered? I am using fread function for reading structures into the file and then I want to print the entries on the screen.

Comment: Can you simplify your code and provide an example of input and expected output?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  This is primarily a question and answer site, but you have not asked a question.  You have posted some code.  Apparently (from the question title) your concern is with the `fread()` and `fwrite()` functions, but you've not shown us what you're getting, what you want to get, the input that you're using etc.  Please see how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: The code is implementation of fread and fwrite functions. The guy shared the code with us to use them in our projects. Thank you bushra

Comment: @MustafaChelik: interesting thought, but the implementation seems to be lacking the key functions, suggesting your hypothesis is wrong.

Comment: @MustafaChelik but the half of the code is not working, the view() function. So, it won't be much helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Windows-specific code and cleaned things up a bit.  The code religiously checks whether each `scanf()` returned the correct value; lazily, it just exits if it doesn't.  It also checks that the calls to `fopen()` work.

Some of the `scanf()` calls were dodgy.  You don't need the `&` in front of a string name, and you do need `%lf` to read a `double` (the phone number — interesting choice of data type).  I made sure that newlines appear in the output.

The printing is a bit better, though there are problems of a sort with long names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu(void); // for choosing a menu
void addacc(void); // for adding account
void view(void);  // for viewing existing list

struct date
{
    int date, month, year;   // struct for date
};

struct customer
{
    char name[40], acctype[10];
    int accno, age;
    double phone;
    float amount;
    struct date dob;  // calling other struct inside struct
    struct date deposit;
    struct date withdraw;
} add;   // struct variable

void addacc(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("cus.txt", "a+");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("ADD RECORD\n");
    printf("Enter today's date(date/month/year) \n");
    if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &add.deposit.date, &add.deposit.month, &add.deposit.year) != 3)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter account number\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &add.accno) != 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter customer's name\n");
    if (scanf("%s", add.name) != 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter customer's age\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &add.age) != 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter customer's phone num\n");
    if (scanf("%lf", &add.phone) != 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter the account type(in words): \n\t 1:Current\n\t 2:Saving\n\t 3:Fixed\n");
    if (scanf("%s", add.acctype) != 1)
        exit(1);
    printf("Almost done! Just enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &add.amount) != 1)
        exit(1);

    fwrite(&add, sizeof(add), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void view(void)
{
    FILE *view;
    int test = 0;
    printf("Customer's List\n");
    printf("\tCustomer's Name:");
    printf("\tAccount Number:");
    printf("\tCustomer's Phone No:\n");
    view = fopen("cus.txt", "r");
    if (view == NULL)
        exit(1);

    while (fread(&add, sizeof(add), 1, view) != 0)
    {
        printf("\t%16s", add.name);
        printf("\t%15d", add.accno);
        printf("\t%20.0f", add.phone);
        putchar('\n');
        test++;
    }
    fclose(view);
    if (test == 0)
    {
        printf("NO RECORDS FOUND!");
    }
}

void menu(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter your choice 1, 2\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        exit(1);

    switch (n)
    {
    case 1:
        addacc();
        break;
    case 2:
        view();
        break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter your choice 1, 2
2
Customer's List
        Customer's Name:        Account Number: Customer's Phone No:
            BushraYousuf               12345678         112345987621
        PresidentBarackObama          987654321           2021199920
```

He's got more money stashed away than you have.

Comment: Thank you soo much, believe me from last two days I was stuck at this point and it was not showing the entries I searched about 20 websites and I couldn't identify the error. Finally I made an account yesterday here, I really appreciate it.